# GitHub action: How to check if PR creator is part of a specific team?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to run a Github action that checks if the PR creator is a member of GitHub team "My cool Team" and if so do something.

I'm having trouble understanding how I can leverage the `octokit` team endpoint "Get team membership for a user" https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#teams

The docs explain that the response for https://docs.github.com/en/rest/teams/members#get-team-membership-for-a-user

is

```
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/teams/1/memberships/octocat",
  "role": "maintainer",
  "state": "active"
}
```

if the user is in the team otherwise it returns 404 which i also don't know how to handle?

This is what I wrote:

```
on: pull_request_target

jobs:
  my_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            // If user is member of my_team team do nothing else do something
            // See: https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#teams
            const creator = context.payload.sender.login
            const opts = github.rest.teams.getMembershipForUserInOrg.endpoint.merge({
              org: 'my_org',
              team_slug: 'My cool Team',
              username: ???? #How do I get the username of who opened the PR?
            })
            const response = await github.paginate(opts)

           
            if (response.state <> "active") {
                return
              }

            // User is not in the team continue to do something...
```

Any thoughts how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code snippet

```js
const creator = context.payload.sender.login
```

The `creator` variable is the username of who opened the PR. Also, await for the result of `getMembershipForUserInOrg()` could be enough for your need. Something like:

```js
            const creator = context.payload.sender.login
            const result = await github.rest.teams.getMembershipForUserInOrg({
              org: context.repo.owner,
              team_slug: 'my-cool-team',
              username: creator
            })
            console.log(creator, result) // do whatever you want
```

Comment: My goal is to check if the creator is part of the team, if not I want to post a reply with some message. I'm not sure how I do that if condition?

Comment: Then beside `pull_request_target`, you will also need to use `issue_comment` which will beyond this question's topic. Consider consulting the GitHub's documentation at [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows) to learn more about event trigger. Also, it can be easier to do if you get the PR number, query the author via the REST api and do whatever you want :)

Comment: Lets leave the issue comment out of scope then.. If we can focus just about how to get the if condition right regardless of what is the action to be done in it. For the moment the answer you gave doesn't provider how to do the if, i believe this is a 1 line fix to your code I just can't find the syntaxt

Comment: Your code provided in the question description isn't correct, so it isn't an if-condition thing if you keep using the `await github.paginate(opts)` since it's wrong. My code already fixes your issue, all you need to do is replace my `console.log()` line, adding your `if` condition to check the `result` object and do whatever you want.

Comment: btw, since I don't know how will you use the `result` object so I couldn't provide you an example, since it's just a simple if-condition, then you can just simply check the part you're interested in the `result` object. If you don't know what's in the object, read the documentation or do a trail run and see the output of the `console.log()` and then you'll know what might be the info you're interested. The result should contain the state of the membership and the member's role if the user is in the given team.

Comment: To my understanding the result should be boolean. Either you are member or you are not  but this is not the case this is the object returned https://docs.github.com/en/rest/teams/members#get-team-membership-for-a-user which means if user is a member it returns object otherwise it returns 404